# Register Event callbacks with pywin32

Tags: python, com, pywin32

I am having difficulty figuring out how to receive events using pywin32.  I have created code to do some OPC processing.  According to the generated binding in the gen_py folder I should be able to register event handlers and it gives me the prototypes I should use... for example:

```
# Event Handlers
# If you create handlers, they should have the following prototypes:
#   def OnAsyncWriteComplete(.......)
```

So I have written code that implements the handlers that I am interested in but have not the slightest idea how to get them attached to my client and can not seem to find examples that are making sense to me.  Below I create my client and then add an object that should have events associated with it...

```
self.server = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch(driver)
# I can now call the methods on the server object like so....
new_group = self.server.OPCGroups.Add(group)
```

I want to attach my handler to the new_group object (perhaps to the self.server?) but I can not seem to understand how I should be doing that.

So my questions are:

1. How can I attach my handler code for the events?  Any examples around I should look at?
2. Will the handler code have access to attributes stored on the client "self" in this case?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After quite a bit, I was able to find a way to do this. What I did was find that I could attach my Event handler class to the group.

```
self.server = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch(driver)
# I can now call the methods on the server object like so....
new_group = self.server.OPCGroups.Add(group)

self._events[group] = win32com.client.WithEvents(
    new_group, GroupEvent)
```

Once I had that going it seems to trigger the events, but the events would not run until the end of the script.  In order to get it to process the events that were queued up, I call this which seems to trigger the callbacks to execute.

```
pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
```

Don't know if it will help anyone else but it seems to work for what I am doing.

Comment: that could be late, but in case someone gets stuck in the future:
here is [a full example with multithreading](https://vlasenkov.blogspot.com/2017/03/python-win32com-multithreading.html) as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33212475/2730737)

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for this, it was very helpful. To extend the question, I found I could simply register the driver:

```
import win32com

class MyEvents(object): pass

server=win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch(driver)
win32com.client.WithDispatch(server, MyEvents)
```

I discovered this by performing `help(win32com.client.WithEvents)`