# How to pass arguments to win32com event handler

Tags: python, pywin32, python-multithreading, win32com, pythoncom

The code below works fine. I can't find a way to pass some arguments to `EventHandler` or to call methods of `MainClass` from `EventHandler`. For example instead of using constant `param`, I'd like to pass it through constructor or setter method. I've tried recommendations from [here](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/168666/). But in this case `EventHandler` instance does not catch any events (or at least nothing appears in stdout).

```
class EventHandler:
    param = "value"    
    def OnConnected(self):
        print 'connected'
        return True

class MainClass:
    def run(self):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Lib.Obj")
        session_id = pythoncom.CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(pythoncom.IID_IDispatch, session)
        args = { 's_id': session_id, }
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run_in_thread, kwargs=args)
        thread.start()

    def run_in_thread(self, s_id):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        session = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvent(
            pythoncom.CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(s_id, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch),
            EventHandler
        )
        session.connect()
        while True:
            pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = MainClass()
    obj.run()
```

Comment: Read my answer here, this should solve your issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341675/passing-additional-arguments-to-python-callback-object-win32com-client-dispatch/41140003#41140003

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use `WithEvents` function. But this may not be the best way. Also now `handler` and `client` objects are different entities, so this leads to additional mechanisms of interaction between them.

```
class EventHandler:

    def set_params(self, client):
        self.client = client

    def OnConnected(self):
        print  "connected!"
        self.client.do_something()
        return True

client = win32com.client.Dispatch("Lib.Obj")
handler = win32com.client.WithEvents(client, EventHandler)
handler.set_client(client)

client.connect()

while True:
    PumpWaitingMessages()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Here is [a complete example](https://vlasenkov.blogspot.ru/2017/03/python-win32com-multithreading.html).